# Javascript: How can I get progress of a download?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is there any way to get the status and progress of a download managed by the browser (Chrome, Firefox, ...)?
When I click a link and the browser start to download a file, is there any API for Javascript (window, document, ...) to get the status and progress of this download?

I would like to indicate the user the download progress in my html using Javascript, and I want the browser to manage the download, not Javascript+AJAX.

Comment: Havascript? Indeed.

Comment: Is there an api? Nope

Comment: Ups :) Javascript

Comment: But well. Is there any way to do this? If not, why? It could be possible to provide all downloads managed by the browser (and started by your site) in the Window object.

Comment: @epascarello Why not? What's the technical issue here? I think in the Window object the browser can provide that.

Comment: There is no api in JavaScript... ask the browser developers and the standards people why.

Comment: @epascarello Ok. I just tagged this issue with "Firefox" and "Chrome", I hope any developer of those two give me some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Downloads are not visible to Javascript.